# Setting up zxing 2.0 barcode scanner in android app

Tags: android, cordova, zxing, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to setup barcode scanner for an android app. I was able to setup the barcode scanner using the plugin provided by phonegap. That worked fine on some phones but was not working on some HTC phones. I searched online and some one suggested that upgrading to zxing 2.0 should solve the problem. So, I downloaded the zxing-2.0 and followed the following steps:
1. Unzipped the zxing-2.0 and built the core package.
2. Added the android package to eclipse as an Android Project and selected it as library( named zxing-2 ).
3. Added core.jar as an external jar to the zxing-2 which made it build successfully on eclipse.
4. Added the zxing-2 as project dependency of my main app(myApp). Also added core.jar as an external jar in myApp.

MyApp's mainfest.xml now contains( earlier it contained the action name as com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN):

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" 
              android:label="@string/share_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am using the BarcodeScanner.java provided in phone gap plugin to invoke the barcode scanner. I changed the scan() method in it to:

```
//new version
public void scan() {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.ctx.startActivityForResult((Plugin) this, intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
}

//earlier version(it worked with zxing 1.7)
public void scan() {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.ctx.startActivityForResult((Plugin) this, intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The project builds fine but when I run it and trigger the scan, I get the following runtime exception:

```
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phonegap.myApp/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class phonegap
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class phonegap
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:317)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:251)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:444)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:422)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:167)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.phonegap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.phonegap.myApp-1.apk]
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
03-03 19:43:13.499: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 19 more
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here or have I missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: hi Nitesh, can I get your ZXing-2.0's core.jar please? It is hard to build for me cos I am not sure why, it always fail in my cmd, i m using EClipse and window7 btw, whenever i reach to eg. C:/usr/thetmonaye/android-sdk-15> cd core, then it always says, the file canot be fetch,so i need the ZXing 2.0's core pls, kindly give me to thetmon4@gmail.com? :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is that you are trying to integrate by Intent, but are also including `core/` and `android/`. You should never use `android/` like this, and only use `core/` if building your own internal scanning. Remove these entirely.

All you want from the project is `android-integration/` and all you need to do is here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

I don't know Phonegap well, but it's not worth using it on Android for this.